# How to read a csv containing english and thailand charecters in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am not able to split the columns properly when I am reading the CSV file containing data in thai characters and English characters in pandas read_csv.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("test.csv",delimeter=";")
```

Comment: I am getting the first two columns into the first column because of that my columns are getting mismatched.

Comment: hard to answer without some fake data that showcases your problem

Comment: |123|;|1234567|;|1|;|3|;|bahdfhbax!  hi how are you|;| answer|;| ชื่อของฉันคือ|;|น้องๆ ให้บริการเป็นอย่างดีค่ะ|;|น้องๆ ให้บริการเป็นอย่างดีค่ะ|

Comment: @Ian Quah the above is the fake data, please find that

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a file with a different [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) than the western standard, *UTF-8*. You should specify the encoding of the text of the file you are trying to read. In your case this is *TIS-620*. Each language has its own encoding so just look up the encoding of the language next time you are trying to read a different encoding than *UTF-8* from a file.

```
import csv

with open("test.txt", encoding="TIS-620") as file:
    data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
```